# Use NSTextField as replacement for NSLabel

Tags: swift, macos

As AppKit doesn't provide an NSLabel, we need to find something similar. NSTextField might be the thing I need?

How to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20169310/7166841) in Swift?

```
[textField setBezeled:NO];
[textField setDrawsBackground:NO];
[textField setEditable:NO];
[textField setSelectable:NO];
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, NSTextField is the right one.

It's what Xcode suggests when you ask for a label:

[image]

You can create the label from Interface Builder, or from code:

[image]

And set your values like this, for example:

```
let tf = NSTextField()
tf.isBezeled = false
tf.drawsBackground = false
tf.isEditable = false
tf.isSelectable = false
```

Comment: Thats what I expected, I've used Labels within my GUI before. I want to integrate it into a TableView cell, so the option with drag n drop it into the Storyboard doesn't work. 

I've created the following table: http://pastebin.com/2NihP2iJ

What I wanted to do is to manually set the attributes to the TextField so it works like a Label, but I don't know OBjective-C and as I know you can't use both in one function / method.

Comment: Ah, no, my fault, *I* was going too fast. :D Thanks.

Comment: No problem, we're all humans, we're all not perfect. Thats life.
Have a nice day, Eric! <3

Comment: Indeed. Have a nice day too, Jakob. :)